# C++: Template argument list

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that will take an original array, create one that is twice as large, and then have the original values appear twice.

I am pretty sure my code for the function is correct, but I cannot figure out what I need to put in main to make it work. I am currently getting "Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction" and "Cannot refer to class template 'array' without a template argument list" compiler errors.

Any ideas on what I need to fix to make this work?

```
void repeatArray(double **array, int size)  

{ //Dynamically allocate array that holds an amount of elements = size  
    double *resize = new double[size * 2];  
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  
{
    resize[i] = (i + 1) * 2;  
    delete [] *array;  
    *array = resize;  
}
}

int main()  
{
const int size = 5;  
**array[] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};  

repeatArray(double **array, size);  
for (int i; i < size; i++)  
{
    cout << array;  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to allocate a one dimensional array and make a pointer pointer point to the data that is allocated for a one dimensional array, also you are calling the wrong delete on memory allocated for a one dimensional array.

If the goal is to double the size of an array that you have allocated dynamically using `new`, then you can do the following

```
void resizeArray(int** arr, int new_size) {
    delete[] (*arr);
    *arr = new int[new_size];
    // do your initialization here
}

int main() {
    const int size = 5;
    int* arr = new int[5];
    resizeArray(&int, 5);
}
```

---

Although keep in mind that when you are working with dynamic arrays.  It is almost always better to use `std::vector` than to roll your own arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In C++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void repeatArray(std::vector<T> &array) {
    int element_count = array.size();
    array.resize(2*element_count);
    for (int i=0; i<element_count; i++)
        array[i+element_count] = array[i];
}

int main() {
    vector<float> array = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
    repeatArray(array);
    for (auto &i : array) {
        cout << i << ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might use `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`

Comment: You should call `reserve` to avoid dangling pointer when resizing though.

Comment: I passed by reference so where is there a pointer? back_inserter calls push_back which will resize when needed.

Comment: So original iterators (`array.begin()`, `array.end()`) are invalidated.